Cannot install Maven artifact even though it seems to be listed in Maven repository
I have this dependency listed in my pom.xml.
<dependency>
    <groupId>ambit</groupId>
    <artifactId>ambit2-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.9</version>
</dependency>

However, when I type in mvn -U install, I get the following error.

The following artifacts could not be resolved: ambit:ambit2-core:jar:2.4.9 (absent): Could not find artifact ambit:ambit2-core:jar:2.4.9 in central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)

When I go to https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2, I cannot locate this group. Any ideas on how to install this dependency?

Go to https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/ambit/ambit2-core/2.4.9 and look at the following note:
Note: this artifact is located at Ideaconsult repository (https://nexus.ideaconsult.net/content/repositories/releases/)

You have to add the above repository into your settings.xml in order to resolve that dependency.

Thank you. That helped. However, as I am looking down, it has a compile dependence to org.openscience.cdk:cdk-isomorphism:1.4.11, which does not exist in the Central Maven Repository. Any ideas on how to get that jar?

Thak you. Please accept my solution. For the other issue do the same: look at https://mvnrepository.com for further details on that artifact.
